# Mysql Subquery returns only one result, even with more than one ID in the list

Tags: mysql, subquery

I have 2 tables (groups and attributes), with groups having more than one attribute listed by ID (ie: 1,2,3, ..) and when listing them I would like to display the attributes that are part of each group.

The problem is precisely in the subquery, it returns only the first item. If I manually enter the values (i.e.: 1,5,9 ...) it returns correctly, but when using the parent query field (groups.attributes) the error happens.

I apologize for having initially posted the issue without following community standards, I am not in the habit of asking questions here.

### GROUPS TABLE

```
ID    NAME          ATTRIBUTES
1     Shoes         1,2,3
2     Pants         4,5
...
```

### ATTRIBUTES TABLE

```
ID    IDENTIFIER
1     Size
2     Color
3     Voltage
...
```

### QUERY

```
SELECT 
  G.id, G.name, 
  COALESCE(
    (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(A.name SEPARATOR ', ') FROM attributes A WHERE A.id IN (G.attributes)), 
    '-'
  ) AS attributes_names  
FROM 
  groups G
```

Surely someone will have a better suggestion or a solution that my eyes don't see right now.

Comment: please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query and malke a [mre]

Comment: @nbk thanks! My apologies! I don't publish often, I ended up not really detailing the problem. Already corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `FIND_IN_SET` because ATTRIBUTES is a string.

`IN` clause needs individual parameters so only (IN (1,2,3) or IN('1','2','3')

Also please take a good look at [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad) and think about normalizing your tables, which makes the queries easier.

Last GROUPS is a reserved word in MySQL, you should avoid using these

> ```
> CREATE TABLE `GROUPS`
>     (`ID` int, `NAME` varchar(5), `ATTRIBUTES` varchar(5))
> ;
>     
> INSERT INTO `GROUPS`
>     (`ID`, `NAME`, `ATTRIBUTES`)
> VALUES
>     (1, 'Shoes', '1,2,3'),
>     (2, 'Pants', '4,5')
> ;
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE ATTRIBUTES
>     (`ID` int, `IDENTIFIER` varchar(7))
> ;
>     
> INSERT INTO ATTRIBUTES
>     (`ID`, `IDENTIFIER`)
> VALUES
>     (1, 'Size'),
>     (2, 'Color'),
>     (3, 'Voltage'),
>     (4, 'length'),
>     (5, 'wifdth')
> ;
> ```

> ```
> SELECT 
>   G.id, G.name, 
>   COALESCE(
>     (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(A.IDENTIFIER SEPARATOR ', ') FROM ATTRIBUTES A WHERE FIND_IN_SET (A.ID,G.attributes)), 
>     '-'
>   ) AS attributes_names  
> FROM 
>   `GROUPS` G
> ```
>
> ```
> id | name  | attributes_names    
> -: | :---- | :-------------------
>  1 | Shoes | Size, Color, Voltage
>  2 | Pants | length, wifdth
> ```

> ```
> SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(A.IDENTIFIER SEPARATOR ', ') FROM ATTRIBUTES A WHERE  FIND_IN_SET (A.ID,'1,2,3')
> ```
>
> ```
> | GROUP_CONCAT(A.IDENTIFIER SEPARATOR ', ') |
> | :---------------------------------------- |
> | Size, Color, Voltage                      |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1052f0fefbd27f31d921419358964563)*

Comment: Yes, I used groups just to simplify, my table is called product_attribute_groups. It worked perfectly, thank you very much.